# iOS: Change alpha of image view with gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, alpha

I want to change the alpha of image with the gestures like up and down or right and left.
I don't want to use slider for that.

Is it possible to do this if yes then please tell me how or i have to use slider for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement method on view or view controller

```c
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

    NSLog(@"location: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

    // Example:
    // alpha depends on location.x related to view bounds width
    CGFloat alpha = (self.bounds.size.width - location.x) / self.bounds.size.width;
    NSLog(@"alpha: %@",@(alpha));
}
```

where you can check `location.x` or `location.y`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like following :

First attach tap `GestureRecognizer` to view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourTapMethod:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then, in gesture recognizer handler do what do you want:

```
-(void)yourTapMethod{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){

     imageView.alpha = //add any value (like 0.2f);  
  }
```

Comment: I know how to apply gestures to views but i want to change the alpha of image view like we change using slider. in my case i dont want to use slider for that

Comment: have you seen the app Prisma? I want to change the alpha like that on image view gesture.